# Iterating ListView items in Android

Tags: android, listview, iteration, listviewitem

I want to iterate a list of items into a ListView. This code below is not enough to iterate all the items into the list because of the weird behaviour of getChildCount() function which only returns the visible item count.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.getChildCount(); i++) {
   item = (View)list.getChildAt(i);
   product = (Product)item.getTag();
   // make some visual changes if product.id == someProductId
}
```

My screen displays 7 results and when there are more than 7 items into the list, it's not possible to access to the 8th item or so.. Only visible items..

Should I use ListIterator instead?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you populating the data , If you are using an adapter, overide the getCount() method of the list adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize your list adapter's `getView()` method, and put your check inside it to check if the current item's id matches:

```
Product product = items.get(position);
if(product.id == someProductId) {
    //make visual changes
} else {
    //reset visual changes to default to account for recycled views
}
```

Since typically only the visible items only exist at a specific time, getView is called whenever more need to be seen. They're created at that time, typically recycling views from the now-invisible items in the list (hence why you want to reset the changes if the criteria does NOT match).

Comment: Hi kcoppock. Thanks for your reply. Now it works as I expected except it's not updating the visible part of the UI until I scroll. Is there any event that I can trigger to refresh the UI.

Comment: Yup, you can call `listView.notifyDatasetChanged();`. That will refresh the ListAdapter, however, it should be correct even before scrolling; getView gets called as each view is built. Can you post your ListAdapter's code into the original question?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm so sorry to accept it that late. I thought I already accepted. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

So @kcoppock solved your first problem it seems you got another problem. How to update the view item? The android SMS application shows one way:

1. create your own list view item like this:

   ```
   public class MyListItem extends RelativeLayout {
   ...
   }
   ```

   in your list view item layout file:

   ```
   < MyListItem  android:layout_width=.....>
   ...
   </ MyListItem >
   ```
2. and in your code, when your view item can be seen, register `MyListItem` as a data changed listener(the data is up to you). I mean, when your data changed, then you can update the item directly.

Check out the SMS application source code to read more.

Answer (score 0):

The number of views in the ListView(7) is different from the number of items in the adapter(which is more than 7) .Try to use a BaseAdapter.